# Remember a persons name

Tags: osx, ios, web-browser, cross-platform

I'm in search of software to **remember** several things of a person:

- Name
- Affiliation (Lover / Familiy / Work / ...)
- Any notes I want to keep (Went on vacation to Bahamas, ...)

Example: [Namerick](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/namerick-remember-names/id473146248) (*only ios*)

I want to practice this, as forgetting the name of my colleagues and friends makes me furious, the platform I use most is macOs and iPhone. However I'm looking for a **cross-platform** solution where I can use both!

Comment: Personally, I'd use the address book of your favorite email program for this. For example for Mozilla Thunderbird. You can add all kinds of data to a record there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm using a combination of pen and paper + technology as no solution satisfied my needs currently.